# Docker con Spring War, MySQL y tomcat no funciona

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, docker, docker-compose

He estado intentando durante bastante tiempo desplegar una aplicacion web hecha en Spring con Docker pero por ahora no he conseguido tener exito, cuando envío la solicitud con Postman me tira un 404.
Utilizo hibernate para la creacion de tablas, con MySQL y Tomcat como servidor.

En el Spring, antes de compilar, el .properties es:

```
#logging
logging.level.root=info
logging.file.name=application.org

#port
server.port=8095
#server.servlet.context-path=/proyecto
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
#spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

#database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://backend:3307/proyectodiagrama     #cambiar a localhost 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=


#crear tablas la primera vez:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#debugSql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#seguridad
spring.security.user.name=usuario 
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

Mi Dockerfile es:

```
# docker build -t mywebapp .

FROM tomcat:9.0

RUN cp -r webapps.dist/manager webapps/manager

ADD proyecto.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

VOLUME /usr/local/tomcat/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]


# docker run -p 8080:8080 mywebapp
```

Proyecto.war se encuentra en el mismo directorio que el Dockerfile.

El docker Compose es el siguiente:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    backend:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - /opt/test:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: proyectodiagrama
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: sss
        ports:
            - 3307:3306
    web:
        depends_on:
            - backend
        image: tomcat
        volumes:
            - ./target/proyecto.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/proyecto.war
        ports:
        - '8080:8080'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: proyectodiagrama
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: sss
            SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL: jdbc:mysql://backend:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

En cuanto ejecuto el docker compose up, no da ningún error pero no consigo conectar con la url "http://localhost:8080/proyecto/estaciones/crear", y aunque entre en el navegador y escriba localhost:8080/proyecto también da 404. Agradecería si me pudierais ayudar.